# problem with put pagination in a line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please see this eg: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show => i not want put pagination following each other, i want put are all they in a line.

What is your comment?

Comment: You would need to increase the width of the divs wrapping your pagination.

Comment: `width` in my code not have status fix, it is always changing with adding and remove pagination. what do i do?

Comment: `hesar_pagination` and `hesar_number` both have fixed widths.  This is causing your pagination to wrap to a second line.

Comment: If i put in `hesar_pagination` this: `width: auto;` and in `hesar_number` this: `width: auto;` is in my page disorganization. How can with maintain the mode page, this would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what about nobr html tag or css white-space: nowrap ?

See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_NOBR.html
or http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp